# How to protect s3 files from downloading using downloadhelper plugin

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have my video files stored in s3 bucket.

My files are downloadable using a plugin called `Video DownloadHelper`. It has two option download `Using Browser` and download `Using Companion App`.

I'm restricting S3 files access by setting  bucket policy with specific http referrer.

After adding this policy now it is not possible to download `Using Browser` but able to download `Using Companion App`.

How can I restrict downloading files using the second method as well? The bucket policy I have set is given below. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Id": "http referer policy example",
   "Statement": [
     {
       "Sid": "Allow get requests referred by www.example.com and example.com.",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": "*",
       "Action": "s3:GetObject",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
       "Condition": {
         "StringLike": {"aws:Referer": ["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
       }
     },
      {
        "Sid": "Explicit deny to ensure requests are allowed only from specific referer.",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
        "Condition": {
          "StringNotLike": {"aws:Referer": ["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Not sure how to block this personally but I know the app is open sourced, it could help other posters, the source that gets requests is available at github: https://github.com/mi-g/vdhcoapp/blob/master/app/request.js

Answer (score 0):

Once your file is loaded in the browser, It can be downloaded. what you can do is to generate a signed URL for the images, which is valid for a short time.

set the `src` for the images to an API which redirects to a `signed URL generated by the backend`, so while inspecting the browser it will show the `signed URL` as `SRC` but that URL can't be reused. But this will only prevent the reuse of the image URLs or if the download-helper is using the URL to download the image. Here whenever the user refreshes the page a new URL will be generated and send to browser.

Eg:

```
   <img src=https://api-url/image/image-id>
```

and in your backend do something similar to

```
response.redirect(signed-url)
```